# PHP Gerando PDF

Tags: php

Bom estou com um problema em um formulário, basicamente estou pegando as informações de um formulário HTML com o metodo POST para uma página PHP, preciso gerar um pdf apartir desse formulário e consegui fazer isso com o mPDF (6.0) até ai esta tudo certo, porém so consigo salvar 1 pdf, creio que seja por conta do nome do arquivo ele esteja substituindo o arquivo que já existe na pasta.

Gostaria de saber se consigo criar algo como um auto increment para evitar arquivos com o mesmo nome, ou se posso usar uma variavel para pegar um campo do formulário e utiliza-lo como nome.

Segue o código de saída do PDF com a classe mPDF:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$css = file_get_contents("css/estilo.css");

$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($pdf);

$mpdf->Output('-local-\form.pdf', 'F');
```

Como disse está funcionando porém só consigo manter 1 arquivo salvo.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para não sobrescrever o arquivo o nome deve ser único na pasta.

```
$codigo = date('YmdHis.U');
$arquivo = '-local-\form-' . $codigo . '.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'F');
//Saída: form-20170801064711.pdf
```

Obs.: Procuro usar a data para saber quando ocorreu o envio do arquivo na pasta.

Comment: E se dois usuários on-line submeterem o formulário às 06:47:11 de 1°/08/2017?

Comment: Havia esquecido de implementar os milissegundos. E concordo que sem os milissegundos duas requisições eram possível de ocorrer no mesmo tempo.

Comment: Justo e perfeito!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Dinamicamente você pode usar algum dos valores submetidos pelo form como nome do arquivo. Por exemplo, concatenando nome + sublinhado + CPF: *nome_cpf.pdf* (se existir isso no seu form e você tiver certeza que não haverá repetição desta combinação de valores). Mas se qualquer nome de arquivo serve, deixe o PHP gerar um para você, assim:

```
$mpdf->Output('-local-\\'.uniqid().'.pdf', "F"); 
// exemplo: eb98xzzhr8dervre.pdf
```