# Pergunta: Exemplo de envio de arquivos/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber se há algum exemplo na internet, que ao logar/fazer session em uma conta admin, possa enviar arquivos a uma determinada conta pra fazer o download do arquivo. 
Por exemplo: um arquivo pdf

Oque posso estar vendo pra tentar fazer algo similar a isso?

Obrigado!

Comment: "enviar arquivos a uma determinada conta" está muito incompleto. enviar por onde? que conta? do mesmo sistema?. bom vou responder interpretando o que disse.

Comment: Desculpe pela demora, mas.. eu tenho um sistema de login com minha session e tudo mais e meu bd, onde eu preciso pelo menos criar um campo onde tenho os "usuarios cadastrados" e nestes usuários selecionar um pra enviar o arquivo e aparecer esse arquivo na conta dele pra fazer o download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar por exemplo um arquivo TXT. Ao usuário logar no sistema, tendo uma pagina para "enviar mensagem em txt para outro usuario".

> (aonde voce escreve o texto e seleciona o usuário).

```
<?php
//Criamos uma função que recebe um texto como parâmetro eo id do usuario que voce selecionou.
function gravar($user, $texto){
    //Variável arquivo armazena o nome e extensão do arquivo e o id de quem recebera esse arquivo quando logar.
    $arquivo = $user."meu_arquivo.txt";

    //Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");

    //Escreve no arquivo aberto.
    fwrite($fp, $texto);

    //Fecha o arquivo.
    fclose($fp);
}

//aqui voce pode chamar essa função depois de escrever o texto na pagina com o input.

gravar($texto_do_input);

?>
```

nesse código acima você salvou um arquivo no servidor, e quando logar com o usuário que você salvou o txt, ele poderá baixar o arquivo.

**Mas como?**

quando o usuário que tem uma msg no sistema, logar. você pode chamar essa função em alguma parte do sistema:

```
<?php
//Criamos uma função que irá retornar o conteúdo do arquivo.
function ler($id_do_usuário_atual_logado){
    //Variável arquivo armazena o nome e extensão do arquivo.
    $arquivo = $id."meu_arquivo.txt";

    //Variável $fp armazena a conexão com o arquivo e o tipo de ação.
    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "r");

    //Lê o conteúdo do arquivo aberto.
    while (!feof ($fp)) {
        $valor = fgets($fp, 4096);

        echo $valor."<br>";
    }
    //Fecha o arquivo.
    fclose($fp);

    //retorna o conteúdo.
    return $arquivo;
}

//por exemplo você pode fazer um botão no sistema com o nome "ver arquivos salvou, ou baixar arquivos salvos, e ai chamar essa função.

$urldoarquivo = ler($id_do_usuário_atual_logado);

?>
```

Repara que a função `ler`, retorna a `url` do arquivo salvo. Agora é fácil. Com a `url` do arquivo é só usar a função do js para baixar seu arquivo.

**Como fazer isso?**

coloca uma função no click do `<a>`, que chama a função ler, e coloca a url no href.

```
//aqui você passa por parâmetro o id da sessão do usuário atual.
<a href='#' id='adw' onclick='DownloadArquivo(<?php echo $session_id;?>)'>baixar arquivos</a>
```

function DownloadArquivo(id) {

```
//voce precisa do ajax para comunicar js com o php
$.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url : 'arquivo_aonde_esta_funcao_ler.php',
     data: { id: id},
     success: function(result){

       //aqui você passa a url do arquivo que retornou e coloca no href.
       $('#adw').attr('href', result.url);
     }  
});

}
```

lembrando que eu só te passei as funções, se voce for usar esse exemplo do ajax você precisa tratar o retorno json. isso no fim do arquivo funcionaria:

```
$array = ['url' => $url];
echo json_encode($array);
```

e ao inves de função é só deixar o código dentro da função no documento php. `(arquivo_aonde_esta_funcao_ler.php)`.

Se quiser fazer a mesma coisa só que com [pdf isso pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/225639/php-gerando-pdf?rq=1)

É claro que você pediu um exemplo, então está ai.